# Recovery of hyperplane arrangements from homotopical data

Tags: hyperplane-arrangements

Given a hyperplane arrangement, one can construct the homotopical data of the poset of faces and the assignment of each facet to the hyperplane in which it belongs. This should be enough to recover the CW structure of the arrangement intersected with a large ball, if I remember correctly.

Is there any means of determining whether such combinatorial data can be achieved by a real hyperplane arrangment?

Given the homotopical data of a real hyperplane arrangement, if one holds $d$ linearly independent hyperplanes fixed, is the space of arrangements with that data necessarily connected? Contractible?